# Detecting Image Tag in html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup for parsing A Page's HTML. Due to broken html the markup is not consistent. I have the following html:

```
<div id='VideoID'>
<a href=#><img src='file.png'></a>
</div>
```

While on other page it's broken as:

```
<div id='VideoID'>
    <a href=#></a>  [Image Tag not enclosed here]
   <img src='file.png'>
    </div>
```

Following Line works for first Snippet as expected:

```
imageURL = imageElement.contents[1].contents[0]['src'].strip()
```

But not for 2nd one which is obvious.

Is there anyway I detect IMAGE tag within DIV of id 'VideoID' no matter it is enclosed in anchor tag or out of it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes with `.descendants`.
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants
You iterate through descendants list and you check the `.name`
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name

Or even easier with CSS selectors:

```
soup.select("div#VideoID img")
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Comment: Yes, CSS selectors are becoming really powerful - and traversing DOM tree is very intuitive with them. Instead of loops and doing things step by step, just one clear line solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `recursiveChildGenerator()` to generate Nth child elements and can find image tag.

example:

```
for child in childs.recursiveChildGenerator():
   image_file = child.findChildren("img")
```

This will help you to find image tag in any hierarchy.

Comment: As you can see http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#generators `.descendants` in my answer is a property made of `.recursiveChildGenerator()`. What's the difference then?